# Stripe payment form display bug on WooCommerce using Stripe by Payment Plugins

Tags: woocommerce, stripe-payments, google-chrome-devtools

I am working on an eCommerce site on Wordpress / WooCommerce.

To capture Credit card payments, Stripe is used. To do that the plugin Stripe by Payment Plugins is used.
But I have a weird issue :
https://watch.screencastify.com/v/9FrZE3OUJMjo046KwbkU

When I reach checkout the form that is displayed for credit card payment is not the one that is supposed to be called.
As you can see on the video, the first form shown is not working and its style is not optimized for conversion.
But once I open Chrome dev tools and reload the page a new form is called, and it is the good one that should be displayed from the beginning.
As you can see this new form works properly, and is way better for conversion rate optimization.

This site uses a custom theme, and if I switch to a more classic theme like "storefront" I don't have this issue anymore, so my guess is that it is theme-related.

I have tried a lot of potential fixes but nothing works so far.
I have also contacted the plugin support but they have never seen this issue before, and advised us to use another form instead of this one. It works but the other available forms are not at all as good for UX design and conversion.

Any clue what might be causing that ?
Thanks a lot !

Comment: You should contact WooCommerce support for help with this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @NolanH Do you think so ?
Since it seems to be theme related and our theme is custom made, I did not thought that would be a good option

Comment: Sure, they should be able to tell you whether their plugin should support whatever customizations you've made, or investigate why it doesn't work like you/they expect.